# Use data from dropdownlist to set value in SNMP-set on Node-red

Tags: json, snmp, node-red

In Node-red I would like to use e.g. the values from a dropdown list to send to an SNMP-set command.
As I understand the snmp-set node uses msg.varbinds to get its data.
But how do I refer to the value coming from the dropdown list in the msg.varbinds input, as it looks JSON to me

This is what I have in the Varbinds window.
I thought I just had to refer to the msg.payload coming from the dropdown element, but that seems to be too easy.

```
[ {
            "oid" : "1.3.6.1.4.1.5835.3.1.3.1.38.1.1",
            "type" : "OctetString",
            "value" : msg.payload
        }
    ]
```

This is by the way the output from my dropdown list in the debug window.

```
9/23/2019, 8:13:04 PMnode: b4c9ef70.0f38d
msg : Object
object
payload: "14300000000"
socketid: "Xc-CPsZX-CouQVRAAAAA"
_msgid: "b77a7c3f.8645c"
```

Here is the flow

```
[{"id":"fd51033f.82b34","type":"snmp set","z":"e5486a7.f6cf798","host":"192.168.0.35","community":"public","version":"1","varbinds":"[ {\n            \"oid\" : \"1.3.6.1.4.1.5835.3.1.3.1.38.1.1\",\n            \"type\" : \"OctetString\",\n            \"value\" : msg.payload\n        }\n    ]","timeout":5,"name":"set freq ","x":620,"y":1940,"wires":[]},{"id":"596c4ff0.67b7b","type":"ui_dropdown","z":"e5486a7.f6cf798","name":"","label":"","tooltip":"","place":"Select option","group":"ca614dce.5eeca","order":11,"width":0,"height":0,"passthru":true,"options":[{"label":"14200","value":"14200000000","type":"str"},{"label":"14300","value":"14300000000","type":"str"},{"label":"14400","value":"14400000000","type":"str"}],"payload":"","topic":"","x":340,"y":1940,"wires":[["fd51033f.82b34","b4c9ef70.0f38d"]]},{"id":"b4c9ef70.0f38d","type":"debug","z":"e5486a7.f6cf798","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"true","x":690,"y":2060,"wires":[]},{"id":"ca614dce.5eeca","type":"ui_group","z":"","name":"Modulator 5","tab":"fe640bc5.c66b48","order":4,"disp":true,"width":"6","collapse":false},{"id":"fe640bc5.c66b48","type":"ui_tab","z":"","name":"Modulators","icon":"rss_feed","order":5,"disabled":false,"hidden":false}]
```

Comment: You need to supply more context here. What have you actually tried and where? e.g. function nodes? change nodes?

Comment: I actually just tried to connect the dropdownlist node to a SNMP-set node. So no function in between.

Comment: We still need a lot more detail about what you're doing.

Comment: Get a value from a dropdwon list selection and use that value to do an SNMP SET, with the DropdwonList node and SNMP set node.  I have no idea how to refer in the SNMp Set node to the value picked from the dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the info sidebar help for the SNMP set node has the bit you are missing:

> `msg.varbinds` may contain varbinds as an array of json objects
>   containing multiple oids, types and values.

This means you need to build the varbinds string and store in the `msg.varbinds` key of the message object and then pass it to the SNMP set node. The easiest way to do this is probably with a function node between the UI dropdown node and the SNMP set node.

```
msg.varbinds = "[ {\n" +
        "\"oid\" : \"1.3.6.1.4.1.5835.3.1.3.1.38.1.1\",\n" +
        "\"type\" : \"OctetString\",\n" +
        "\"value\" : \"" + msg.payload + "\"\n"
    "}\n" + 
"]";

return msg;
```

You should leave the varbinds empty in the SNMP set node config.